# R: make R *not* search for variable in higher environments

Tags: r

By default, in any R code, if a variable name symbol cannot be resolved, R searches for it in higher environments, i.e.

```
y = 1
f = function(x) {
  return(x+y)
}
# returns 2
f(1)
```

works but it really really is not supposed to work. Searching in higher environments is almost never a good idea! For example: I have some code where I have two variables, date and data. Imagine how much time it costs to go over the code and figure out after half an hour (in which you really check the algorithm itself over and over again) that you've misspelled date (you actually wanted data) or vice versa.

After burning too much time on these issues (which create errors that are superhard to track) I wanted to ask whether it is possible to remove this 'feature' from R completely, i.e. is there a tweak or switch that tells R NOT to search for variables in higher environments but to throw an error?

EDIT: maybe It is not clear what I want to achieve here: I do not want to use `f` in the way written above. I want R to warn me that it accessed a variable from a higher context so that I can write the function correctly as `f(x,y)` instead of just `f(x)`... Is that possible?

Greetings,

FW

Comment: from my knowledge, no. This how R works, but it also the beauty of the thing, very permissive and you need to be careful!

Comment: Damn... It seems to me that R is not really a programming language but rather a 'try and play'--language... any script longer than 100 lines in R is suicide...

Comment: Lexical scoping is one of the most powerful parts of R. I'd suggest you should learn how to take advantage of it.

Comment: You can modify your function to something like `if(exists("y", inherits = FALSE))  x + y  else stop("y does not exist") ` and tweak it accordingly to your needs

Comment: Not at all ... it is a very nice functional programming langage. Just think mathematically with functions and when you define them, define them clearly with no variable not declared in argument. This feature you see as a drawback can be turned into an asset.

Comment: @Hong: So could you give me an advice on how to resolve the issue above? Should I rename date and data to other names? But what about the golden rule that variable names should be short and describe the content? So I guess you dont mean that I should learn to use it, you mean that I should learn to appreciate it...which I dont :(

Comment: He rather mean learn how to use it correctly ;)

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel Thats the point: mathematically, a function f(x) cannot refer to y and do something with y .. so math is the contrary of R (from this perspective)

Comment: @DavidArenburg Actually thats the point: When I forget to declare a variable, the language Im using is supposed to remind me of that... which R does not.

Comment: I will not enter into this debate but it's the responsability of the user who is miss-using the langage. It's a failure to define f(x) and add variable y in the corpus of the function. The user should define it as f(x,y) for no ambiguity.

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel I think you misunderstand: I *do not* want to use y from the global context in this function, I want R to remind me that y was not declared in the context of the function. (i.e. after the first time I ran the code, the function is f(x,y))

Comment: Take a look [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html)

Comment: I have found a rather unlikely tool that helps with such 'debugging' . In Rstudio you can surround the code and do an "Extract Function".  The parameter list of generated function  straight away tells you  if a funny variable is fooling around  in the code block. After this, just undo the generated function.

Comment: @FabianWerner The first steps in learning a new language are always tough, but it's not the right approach to expect that the language behaves like we wish. Everyone might like a language rather than another; if you don't like R, just use another language. I'm voting to close this question, since it cannot be any useful to anybody and it is quickly becoming an "R is good/bad" debate.

Comment: As a programmer, you should keep track of your variables and impose tests once in a while. A language can not save you from yourself.